# Speech recognization sppech to text does't work in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have programmed this code to convert audio to text. It is not converting entire text. The total duration of the audio is 1.21 minutes. But the program outputs just 4 words from the audio, rest of the conversation from the audio is missing. Can some one please help me to fix this issue. Below is the code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import playsound

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile('Track1.wav') as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.5)
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = (r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-US"))
        print('working on...')
        print(text)
    except:
        print('Sorry.. run again..')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different audio file. If you are getting only a few words for other audio files also, it could be limit of the "free" default Google API key that is used by the recognize_google function in the speech_recognition library. In that case, you will need your own API key to transcribe longer audio files.

Comment: Hi Adnan, Thank you for the response. Can you please tell me how I need to build my own API key to transcribe longer audio files.

Comment: Follow the directions here (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/) to get an account started and get an API key

Comment: Thank you Adnan, the link is really useful.